# Reload the page and visit an URL without open It

Tags: html

How can I visit a URL without open it in new tab/window ?

For example, I have the following HTML:

```
<a href='http://printoriente.com/admin/archive_order_listing.php?Action=restore_order&Order_Id=<?= $orderDetail["orderId"] ?>' class="label-button" target="_blank">
```

How can I make it open in the same window?

Comment: Remove `target="_blank"`

Comment: Take away target="_blank"

Comment: For more on the target attribute of the `A` tag (which in your case you don't need), see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `target='_blank'` , thats it.

Answer (score 1):

change the code like this

```
<a href='http://printoriente.com/admin/archive_order_listing.php?Action=restore_order&Order_Id=<?= $orderDetail["orderId"] ?>' class="label-button">
```

ie remove the target="_blank"

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the page in the same window by changing the target to:

```
 target="_self"
```

Comment: `_self` is the default, so removing it does have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Can't make much sense from your question. What exactly is it that you want to do?

If you want to prevent the page from being opened on clicking the link, the you should probably use click event handler.

```
var oLnk = document.getElementById( 'aId' );
oLink.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you want the page to be loaded in the current window itself without opening the page in a new tab, set `target` attribute to `_self` or drop it as it is the default.

Other possible solution include redirect, where the php you are linking to can set a redirect using `header` function.